# Using pytrends library with PowerBI

Tags: powerbi-desktop, google-trends

I am trying to extract data from Google Trends by using the pytrends library to analyze it in MS PowerBI by using the following script:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrends = TrendReq()
data = pd.DataFrame()

kw_list = ["Bitcoin", "Ethereum"]

pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, timeframe='today 3-m')
data = pytrends.interest_over_time()

print(data)
```

When using the simple script in PowerBI, the date-column suddenly disappears. How can I include the date-column ?

[image: Result when printing the data]

[image: Import in PowerBI]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrends = TrendReq()
data = pd.DataFrame()

kw_list = ["Bitcoin", "Ethereum"]

pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, timeframe='today 3-m')
data = pytrends.interest_over_time()
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(data)
```

Date column is index, you just need to add second last line

Hope this will work
Thanks!